# Kotlin invoke function from sealedSubclasses

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

I would like to check the behavior of overridden function in objects that extend a class without explicitly list them all.

```
sealed class Food{
    open fun optTemp(): Int{
        return 0
    }
}

object Soup : Food() {
    override fun optTemp(): Int {
        return 65
    }
}

object Cake : Food() {
    override fun optTemp(): Int {
        return 20
    }
}

object Rice : Food() {
    override fun optTemp(): Int {
        return 80
    }
}

object Meat : Food() {
    override fun optTemp(): Int {
        return 60
    }
}
```

I would like get all the object with overridden function and invoke them like this:

```
val subclasses: List<KClass<*>> = Food::class.sealedSubclasses

    for (item in subclasses){
//        item.optTemp()

    }
```

How do I do that?

Comment: If they aren't all `object`s, it doesn't really make sense to call this on all subclasses. If they are all `object`s, it's likely you should be using an enum instead of a sealed class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the sealed subclasses are `object`s, you can get the `object` instance using `objectInstance`, and cast it to `Food`. This cast is safe because of the assumption.

```
for (subclass in Food::class.sealedSubclasses) {
    val result = (subclass.objectInstance as Food).optTemp()
    println("$subclass - $result")
}
```

Note that the output is not in any particular order:

```
class Cake - 20
class Meat - 60
class Rice - 80
class Soup - 65
```

As Tenfour suggested in the comments, an enum class might be more suitable in this case.

```
enum class FoodEnum {
    SOUP { override fun optTemp() = 65 },
    CAKE { override fun optTemp() = 20 },
    RICE { override fun optTemp() = 80 },
    MEAT { override fun optTemp() = 60 };
    open fun optTemp() = 0
}
```

You can then do:

```
for (value in FoodEnum.values()) {
    println("${value.name} - ${value.optTemp()}")
}
```

Not only does this not involve reflection, the output will also be in the order in which you have declared the enum constants:

```
SOUP - 65
CAKE - 20
RICE - 80
MEAT - 60
```

---

If the sealed subclasses are not all `object`s, then you need to *somehow* find instances of each sealed subclass, cast to `Food` if needed, and call `optTemp` on them. After all, `optTemp` is an instance method, so you need an instance to call it.